# Python / Pandas parse string to date and time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column containing strings that represent date and time like this:

```
0    Fri Oct 19 17:42:31 2018
1    Fri Oct 19 17:42:31 2018
2    Fri Oct 19 17:42:31 2018
3    Fri Oct 19 17:42:31 2018
4    Fri Oct 19 17:42:31 2018
```

How can I parse the strings to get the time and the data in datetime format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
['Fri Oct 19 17:42:31 2018'],
['Fri Oct 19 17:42:31 2018'],
['Fri Oct 19 17:42:31 2018'],
['Fri Oct 19 17:42:31 2018'],
['Fri Oct 19 17:42:31 2018']],
columns=['Date'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Yields:

```
                 Date
0 2018-10-19 17:42:31
1 2018-10-19 17:42:31
2 2018-10-19 17:42:31
3 2018-10-19 17:42:31
4 2018-10-19 17:42:31
```

Per @ALollz's comment, you can specify the format to improve performance:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
```

Comment: And you can speed up the parsing greatly by specifying `format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'`

Comment: Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 1):

You can try `df['column_name']=pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'])`. This will convert the datetime you have in string to datetime object and store in the same column. Let me know if this works on your dataframe. You have to `import pandas as pd` for this to work though.